# Manim axes position

Tags: python, manim

Is it possible to move the axis position? I want to plot more scientific data, e.g., voltage over time. If some of the voltage values are negative they cross the x axis which makes the plot look bad as I also want to have labels for x and y.

See the following code:

```py
from manim import *

class LineGraphExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        plane = NumberPlane(
            x_range = (0, 7),
            y_range = (-2, 5),
            x_length = 7,
            y_length = 5,
            axis_config={"include_numbers": True},
        )
        plane.center()
        y_label = plane.get_y_axis_label("\\text{Voltage [V]}", edge=LEFT, direction=LEFT, buff=0.4)
        x_label = plane.get_x_axis_label("\\text{Time [$\mu$s]}", edge=DOWN, direction=DOWN, buff=0.4)
        self.add(y_label)
        self.add(x_label)
        line_graph = plane.plot_line_graph(
            x_values = [0, 1.5, 2, 2.8, 4, 6.25],
            y_values = [1, 3, 2.25, -1.5, 2.5, 1.75],
            line_color=GOLD_E,
            vertex_dot_style=dict(stroke_width=3,  fill_color=PURPLE),
            stroke_width = 4,
        )
        self.add(plane, line_graph)
```

Here, I would like the x axes to intersect with y at -2 (i.e., having the x axes at the bottom of the graph).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is not directly possible using the NumberPlane parameters. I found a kind of hacky approach to solve this:

```py
plane = NumberPlane(
            x_range = (0, 7),
            y_range = (-2, 5),
            x_length = 7,
            y_length = 5,
            axis_config={"include_numbers": True},
            y_axis_config={"numbers_to_exclude": [-2]}
        )
plane.center()
plane.x_axis.move_to(plane.coords_to_point(3.6, -2.2))
plane.y_axis.add_numbers([0])
y_label = plane.get_y_axis_label("\\text{Voltage [V]}", edge=LEFT, direction=LEFT, buff=0.4)
x_label = plane.get_x_axis_label("\\text{Time [$\mu$s]}", edge=DOWN, direction=DOWN, buff=0.4)
...
```

[image: solution image]

I removed the -2 tick on the y-axis and added the 0 one. Hope this is fine.